# Scanning GitHub repo using Gitleaks

Tags: docker, github, gitleaks

I'm scanning my GitHub repo to find hardcoded passwords in the source code. I'm using Gitleaks for that and running it by docker commands. The size of the repo is 2 Gb. The scan has gone for 14 hours and still going and not showing any progress bar or anything. My question is does it generally take Soo long for it or is something not right?

Comment: This seems like a question for the developer(s) of Gitleaks, but if it is answerable here it'd be hard to comment on your specific scenario without seeing the specific commands you ran.

Comment: Well this is the commands I used.                                        export SSH_KEY_DIR=$(echo $HOME)/.ssh
export SSH_KEY_NAME=id_rsa
export REPO="git@github.com:zricethezav/gitleaks.git"

docker run --rm --name=gitleaks \
    --mount type=bind,src=${SSH_KEY_DIR},dst=/root/.ssh,readonly \
    zricethezav/gitleaks \
        --ssh-key=/root/.ssh/${SSH_KEY_NAME} \
        --verbose \
        --repo=${REPO}